# Communciation between nested custom components

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<outer-ce>
  <div>
    <inner-ce></inner-ce>
  </div>
</outer-ce>
```

Say the `<inner-ce>` component has been loaded and defined first, and it doesn't know (hardcoding) what it is inside of. It wants to communicate to the parent custom component.

Normally, this can be done by firing off a custom event that is listened to by the outer component, which can capture the event bubbled up and use a callback to communicate with the inner component.

However, if this event is fired off in the constructor of the inner component, and the outer component has not yet been defined, the event won't be captured, as the outer component has not been constructed.

It would also not be possible to use `customElements.whenDefined()`, because the inner component doesn't know what is the name to watch for, unless it traverses the node tree to find some tag name with a hyphen.

Is there some way to address this requirement?

One way possibly is to have a some sort of a jobs queue, but comes with its own challenges. The inner component fires off an event that travels all the way up and is collected. That high level component looks at the `path` property of that event and determine the name of the outer component, then adds a callback to the queue. When the outer component is being constructed, it checks this queue. But this will require each component to have this checking queue logic implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getParentCustomComponent(e: Element) {
  let parent = e,
    isCustomComponent = false,
    hasParent = true;

  do {
    parent = parent.parentElement || (parent.parentNode as ShadowRoot).host
    if (!parent) {
      hasParent = false
    } else {
      isCustomComponent = parent.tagName.includes('-')
    }
  } while (!isCustomComponent && hasParent)

  return isCustomComponent ? parent : null
}

const parentComponent = getParentCustomComponent(this)

if (parentComponent) {
  const dispatchEvent = () => this.dispatchEvent(msg)
  customElements.whenDefined(parentComponent.tagName.toLowerCase()).then(dispatchEvent.bind(this))
}
```

Using the code above will get you the parent component by traversing up the node tree. Then, when the component is registered, the `.whenDefined()` promise fulfils, and the custom event `msg` can then be fired. off.